# How can i remove a tuple from a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

How can i remove a tuple from a list in Dictionaries? And if necessary put this one removed tuple in an other dictionary?

```
{'name': '...', 'hand_cards': [('...', ...), ('...', ...), ('...', ...)]}
```

Comment: seems like all the values of `'hand_cards'` is list of tuples. so simply just redefine `'hand_cards' = []`. Can you specify more detailed question?

Comment: Its difficult to redefine hand cards because for each player the handcard_list will be resetted, so that the new cards don't mix up with the old ones

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your dictionary (based on what you wrote) looks like this

```
diction = {'name': 'Name', 'hand_cards': [('A', 0), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)]}
```

If you want to remove a tuple for which you know that satisfies a condition, let's say you want to remove x=('B', 1) tuple, for which x[0]='B' and x[1]=1 then run through each tuple and check this (or those) conditions.

```
# New dictionary to save removed tuple(s)
new_diction = {}
# Or dictionary with list containing all removed tuples
new_diction2 = {'hand_cards':[]}

# Run through each tuple inside the list of dictionary with key='hand_cards'
for tupl in diction['hand_cards']:
    if tupl[0]=='B':
        diction['hand_cards'].remove(tupl)
        new_diction['hand_cards'] = tupl # Add tuple to new dictionary
        new_diction2['hand_cards'].append(tupl) # Add tuple to a list in the new dictionary
```

Results :

```
>>> diction           
{'name': 'Name', 'hand_cards': [('A', 0), ('C', 2)]}

>>> new_diction           
{'hand_cards': ('B', 1)}

>>> new_diction2              
{'hand_cards': [('B', 1)]}
```